# MySQL select id which is not in specific date and time

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, select

I have two tables name `cars` and `booking`.
What i want to find is the available cars for booking which in simple is selecting the car details from `cars` whose id is not in booking table on specific date and time.

the booking table has the columns `pick_date(date),drop_date(date),pick_time(time),drop_time(time),car_id(int),booking_id(int) blah blah`.

Now i am stuck in getting the available cars. Will you please guide me how i do it in mysql. Below is 4 of the columns of Booking Table.

```
Pick_Date   Drop_Date    Pick_Time        Drop_Time
----------  -----------  -----------      --------------
2015-01-15  2015-01-15   09:00:00.000000  10:00:00.000000
```

Comment: No sir thats totally diifferent thing

Comment: What is the problem and what query did you use? Dates and times do not have any format, they are binary values.

Comment: Yes, the question that RiggsFolly referred to is totally the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT c.car_id
FROM cars c 
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT car_id 
            FROM bookings 
            WHERE '2015-01-15 11:00:00' BETWEEN CAST(CONCAT(Pick_Date, ' ', Pick_Time) AS DATETIME) AND CAST(CONCAT(Drop_Date, ' ', Drop_Time) AS DATETIME) 
          ) AS A ON c.car_id = A.car_id 
WHERE A.car_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Applying functions to fields like this prevents the database from using indexes and results in a full table scan.

Comment: Thanks I was Stuck from many hours in that and you have given the answer very quick and great. Bundle of Thanks

Comment: Will you explian @PanagiotisKanavos???

Comment: The way this statement is written, the server has to calculate the datetime for each row in the table *before* checking the date ranges, so it can't use any indexes that cover the date and time columns. This will kill performance even in a relatively small database. If you had a proper datetime column you could use a range query (eg `pick_dt between @pickdt and @dropdt`)  the server could use any indexes that covered it to check only the rows that satisfy the condition

Comment: Will you alter the query please i am a newBie @PanagiotisKanavos

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a `left join` or `not in` or `not exists`.  The `left join` looks like

```
select c.*
from cars c left join
     bookings b
     on c.car_id = b.car_id and
        @pickdt <= addtime(drop_date, drop_time) and
        @dropdt >= addtime(pick_date, pick_time)
where b.car_id is null;
```

The variables `@pickdt` and `@dropdt` are the pick up and drop off times you are looking for.  This checks for any overlap between that period and a booking period.  It chooses cars that have no overlap at all.

Note:  you should store datetime values in a single column, not two separate values with the date and time.

Comment: Applying functions to fields like this prevents the database from using indexes and results in a full table scan. A single column would remove the issue. As it is, the `WHERE` statement should be broken in a part that compares the dates and a part that compares the times only if the dates are the same. Very ugly, but the only way to ensure performance in production

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos . . . This would probably not result in a "full table scan" but in an index scan, because of the equality condition on `car_id`.  Storing the date/time values in a single field, though, would allow the use of a composite index, which should speed the query.

Comment: The only condition on `car_id` is the null check on the joined results so it's not selective. It really depends on the underlying data statistics and how the query optimizer decides to execute the query. Performance will be really bad in either case

Answer (score 0):

You can use **"NOT IN"** of MySql.Read for this if still need help please comment.

```
SELECT * FROM cars WHERE cars.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM booking);
```

Hope this query will help you.